# Keyboard layout with sub-layouts like in Windows

Tags: 17.04, keyboard-layout

Windows has very convenient keyboard layout system. There is a set of main languages with one shortcut to switch them and on every main language can be defined a subset of languages which can be switched with different shortcut.

Is it possible to make something similar in Ubuntu 17.04?

Comment: Ubuntu already has it in a more sensible way. The Windows way is actually less intuitive. What exactly do you want Ubuntu to do differently regarding keyboard layouts?

Comment: @MichaelBay I want to switch English <-> Ukrainian/Russian with Alt+Shift and when I'm on Ukrainian/Russian to switch Ukrainian <-> Russian with Ctrl+Shift.

Comment: It's Super (Windows key) + space by default.